# Two teams are playing a best-of-7 tournament. Each team has a 50% chance of winning. What is the probability that they reach the 7th game?

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution

Two teams are playing a best-of-7 tournament. Each team has a 50% chance of winning. What is the probability that they reach the 7th game?

My initial thought would be that it is the probability of no teams win 4 games out of 6 games, so I calculated: $$1 - \binom{6}{4}0.5^40.5^6$$

Can someone point out what is wrong with my logic?

Comment: What events, exactly, do the $0.5^4$ and the $0.5^6$ each stand for?

Comment: sorry, typo in the equation, I meant $0.5^4$ and $0.5^2$

Comment: So, you're not quite on the right track. If the teams are called A and B, then $\binom{6}{4} .5^4 .5^2$ would be the chance that team A wins **exactly** four games of the first six, and team B wins **exactly** two games: that is, it's the number of rearrangements of the string AAAABB, divided by the total number of six-letter strings with letters A and B.

Comment: Here's a hint: the series will go to seven games only if each team wins exactly three games of the first six.

Comment: I am aware the answer is $\binom{6}{3}.5^3.5^3$. How should I foumulate the solution if I would want to go with the logic of "no team wins 4 games by the 6th game"? I originally thought it is  1 - Pr(a team wins 4 games by the 6th game), which I now think the way I calculated this probability was wrong but I also don't know what is right?

Comment: You could do either $$1 - \sum_{k = 4}^6 \operatorname{Pr}(\text{team A wins game $k$, plus exactly $3$ earlier games}) - \sum_{k=4}^6 \operatorname{Pr}(\text{team B wins game $k$, plus exactly $3$ earlier games})$$ or as $$1 - \sum_{k=4}^6 \operatorname{Pr}(\text{team A wins exactly $k$ of the first $6$ games}) - \sum_{k=4}^6 \operatorname{Pr}(\text{team B wins exactly $k$ of the first $6$ games}).$$ These two approaches should give you the same answer. (And since A and B have the same chances of winning, the two sums in each formula are the same.

Answer (score 2):

To reach the 7th game the score must be 3-3 after 6 games.

If a = event: player A wins a game and

b = event: player B wins a game then

one possibility is: aaabbb that is A wins first 3 games and B wins next 3 games.

P(aaabbb) = 0.5^6

Next, work out how many permutations there are of the 6 letters aaabbb. Answer is 6!/(3!3!)

Now multiply 0.5^6 and 6!/(3!3!) which gives answer 5/16

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong with your expression.

1. $\binom64 0.5^40.5^2$ is the probability of the first team winning exactly four games. You also want to exclude the second team winning four games, so you need to multiply by $2$.
2. You need to take into account that a team might win more than four games out of the first six (if you played them all). So you also need to subtract terms corresponding to some team winning five or six games.

Putting all this together, you would get $$1-2\binom640.5^40.5^2-2\binom650.5^50.5^1-2\binom660.5^60.5^0,$$
which would give the right answer. However, it is much easier to calculate by realising that the probability neither team wins four or more games out of six is the probability that they both win exactly three, i.e. $\binom 630.5^30.5^3$.